# creating a relative path with XSL - baselink:SitemapBaseLink --- cocoon, xslt

Tags: xslt, apache-cocoon

The problem is that I have a common "XHTML template" but different relative locations and then some of the pages don't the css file.

I tried to do this on sitemap (cocoon)

```
<map:match pattern="index.html">
    <map:generate src="data/courses-small.xml" type="file"/>
    <map:transform src="xsl/department_listing.xsl" type="xslt2" >
      <map:parameter name="relative_path" value="{baselink:SitemapBaseLink}"/>
    </map:transform>
    <map:serialize type="xhtml" />
  </map:match>
```

And then on the top of the common xsl I have this

```
<xsl:param name="relative_path"/>
```

later I am using the param like this:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title><xsl:value-of select="$displaytitle"/></title>
                 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:8080/cocoon/assignment2/css/style.css" /> 
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="{$relative_path}css/style.css" />
            </head>
```

The problem is that $relative_path is not producing any value, the variable is empty and I am not sure how to fix it.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that the `xsl:param` is specified at global level (not within any template byt just as a child of `xsl:stylesheet`)? If not, this is the cause of the reported issue.

Comment: `relative_path` being empty is not **that** false, in the context of `<map:match pattern="index.html">` (though one could expect `{baselink:SitemapBaseLink}` to output `.`). Could you **(1)** tell us what happens on other matchers (like `<map:match pattern="*/*/index.html">`), **(2)** confirm that Cocoon actually serves the `style.css` file from root-relative path `/css/style.css`, as this is my understanding of your intend, and **(3)** maybe try changing your XSLT like this: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="{$relative_path}/css/style.css" />`.

Comment: Last, but maybe not least, what exact transformer does your `xslt2` type alias?

Answer (score 0):

## $relative_path not producing any value is normal here

`$relative_path` **will logically produce an empty string** if you "match" *an URL that is at the root of your cocoon application*, "folder-wise", like you did in the context of `<map:match pattern="index.html">…</map:match>`

However,

- `$relative_path` will resolve to the `../` string if you "match" an URL that mimics a one-folder structure relative to the root, like in contexts similar to `<map:match pattern="subfolder/index.html">…</map:match>` or `<map:match pattern="*/index.html">…</map:match>`
- it will output as many `../` as necessary depending on pseudo-folder structure (like `../../../..` in the context of `<map:match pattern="foo/*/bar/*/index.html">…</map:match>`)

This should be it.

---

I not, then there may be additional quirks in your setup:

- Make sure you have matchers for your CSS: is it being served successfully by Cocoon if you put its URL in the address bar of your browser?
- Make no typos: maybe it's just on SO and not in your code, but you should fix the HTML in your XSL:

  ```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="{$relative_path}css/style.css" />
  <!-- should read: -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{$relative_path}css/style.css" />
  ```
- As pointed out by [Dimitre Novatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/36305/dimitre-novatchev), make sure your `<xsl:param name="relative_path"/>` is at the right position in your XSL, like:

  ```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
          xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:param name="relative_path" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
      …
    </xsl:template>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
  ```

.